# How to change the value of HTML input of type checkbox on mouse down event

Tags: javascript, html

What would be the best way to accomplish this? This should also (naturally) disable the default on mouse up event, which by default will change the value of the checkbox.

Comment: can u give us more details or submit a fiddle with what u have done so far.

Comment: Please be clear on what you want, and paste some code.

Comment: Please checkout the answers below and mark one as accepted whichever satisfies your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" value="checkme" />
```

JavaScript:

```
var checkbox = document.getElementsByName("mycheckbox")[0];
checkbox.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){

    if(!e){ e = window.event; }

    //Stop checkbox from being toggled on IE9 & Other Browsers
    if(e.stopPropagation){ e.stopPropagation(); }

    //Stop checkbox from being toggled on IE8 and Lower
    else{ e.cancelBubble = true; }

    //Toggle the checkbox yourself instead
    checkbox.checked = (checkbox.checked) ? true : false;

    //And you can also change the value of the checkbox
    checkbox.value="newvalue";
});
```

Comment: This looks like what i wanted. I'll give it a try once i get to my comp.

Comment: `e.stopPropagation()` does not stop checkbox from being toggled by built-in logic. To actually stop the built-in behaviour you need the `e.preventDefault()` and it should be on `click` event, not `mousedown`.

Answer (score 1):

How about setting a click function on the checkbox

```
$(document).on('click', '#myCheckBoc', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).val()); //initial value
    $(this).val('15');    
    alert($(this).val()); //changed value
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/atew6fpr/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

With some assumptions, I have come up with this working code snippet:

Let me know if you need something else.

```js
document.getElementById("checkboxValue").innerHTML = document.getElementById("checkbox").value;

document.getElementById("checkbox").onmousedown = function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  alert("Changing checkbox value...");
  
  this.value = "value2";
  
  document.getElementById("checkboxValue").innerHTML = "value2";
};
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="value1" />
<p>Checkbox Value: <span id="checkboxValue"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
checkbox.onclick = (e) => e.preventDefault(); // disable built-in behaviour
checkbox.onmousedown = (e) => {
    checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
    // if you need it to still fire 'change' event:
    checkbox.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
}
```

Other answers either disabled wrong event (`e.preventDefault()` should be called on `click`, not on `mousedown`) either missed the `mousedown` part.